# Running apt update more than once makes impossible to upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I have a script that updates the system:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt autoremove
```

Sometimes it throws an error saying that the upgrade is locked so It can't upgrade the upgradable packages. When I run the script again, that time `apt update` shows nothing to upgrade, and when It's time to run `apt upgrade` no upgrading because "there is nothing" to upgrade. How can I upgrade the packages that were listed in the first `apt update`?

Real case: now I have Firefox 67.0.3 (version 67.0.4 is available), the first `apt update` showed that there was an update for It. Couldn't upgrade and now when I run `apt update` again no upgrade for Firefox is listed and `apt upgrade` didn't upgrade anything.

I search for this problem in Google but I hadn't success. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks in advance and sorry about my English

Comment: It figures in the `unattended-upgrades.log` file! How could I install them?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that if It appeared in unattended-upgrades then It was not installed. That's weird, I've still the 67.0.3 Firefox version, so there is another problem. Thank you so much anyway! :)

Comment: I'm not seeing 67.0.4 packages yet in released versions of Ubuntu. Where are you seeing that?

Comment: Thank you so much for the Unattended-upgrades logs clarification. If you want make an answer and I'll select it as the correct one! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is that you are occasionally running your script at the same time that Unattended Upgrades is also running.

It's easy to check by looking at your Unattended Upgrades log.

Here's an example of my Unattended Upgrades log for earlier today:

```
$ grep 2019-06-21 /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log

2019-06-21 06:35:25,971 INFO Initial blacklist : 
2019-06-21 06:35:25,986 INFO Initial whitelist: 
2019-06-21 06:35:25,986 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2019-06-21 06:35:25,986 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=disco, o=Ubuntu,a=disco-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=disco, 
2019-06-21 06:36:00,248 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: bind9-host intel-microcode libbind9-161 libdns-export1104 libdns1104 libirs161 libisc-export1100 libisc1100 libisccc161 libisccfg163 liblwres161 libpq5
2019-06-21 06:36:00,248 INFO Writing dpkg log to /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log
2019-06-21 06:37:18,374 INFO All upgrades installed
```

Take a look at line 5 of the log (`Packages that will be upgraded:...`): This list is pulled directly from apt. It's *almost* the same list you get from `sudo apt update`. The default setting for Unattended Upgrades is to use the -security pocket only. Not -updates, not -backports, not PPAs, not third-party repositories. So a few non-security packages may not be installed. You can change this setting.

Now take a look at line 7 of the log (`All upgrades installed`): This is your positive confirmation that all those packages listed on line 5 were successfully upgraded, and the Unattended Upgrades has released the apt lock and terminated for the day. If there was a problem or a failure, or if U-U is still working, then you won't see this line.

You can see that if I had run a manual `sudo apt update` at 06:35, there would have been lots of packages to upgrade. But if I had run `sudo apt upgrade` at 06:38, no packages would have been upgraded...because Unattended Upgrades had already done so.

Comment: You're the best! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I bet it's Ubuntu Software Update getting in the way whenever sudo apt update finishes. You should open up your software update settings and make sure it's set to all the 'Never' options. I don't believe that suppresses the pop-up, but it should prevent it trying to auto-upgrade and locking the files.

For fixing Firefox, I would run `sudo apt install --reinstall firefox` and see if that fixes the issue. If it complains about a lock, you can generally remove it with `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`.

By the way, for your script, you can speed it up by using `sudo -- sh -c 'apt update; apt upgrade --autoremove -y'`

Comment: Thank you for speeding up my script! However the problem is not solved, even when I could reinstall Firefox there are a lot of package like security ones that I don't remember their names, so I can't reinstall all of them :/